# Diagnolization of a matrix such that $A=PDP^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

If possible, I have to find an invertible matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $A=PDP^{-1}$. 
$A = \begin{pmatrix}
-9 & 8 & -8\\
-4 & 3 & -4\\
2 & -2 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$   it's eigen values are 3 with multiplicity 1, and -1 with multiplicity 2

$A-3I_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
-12 & 8 & -8\\
-4 & 0 & -4\\
2 & -2 & -2 
\end{pmatrix}$

For the reduced row echelon from of $A-3I_3$ I get the identity matrix $I_3$ and I would get the same thing for the reduced row echelon form of $A+I_3$ which would mean this matrix is not diagonalizable

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong (might be a minor arithmetic error I just can't identify) because when I look up the answer it says it is diagonalizable with $P =\begin{pmatrix}
-4 & -1 & 1\\
-2 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$ and $D = \begin{pmatrix}
-3 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: spoiler http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordan+form+%7B%7B-9%2C+8%2C+-8%7D%2C%7B+-4%2C+3%2C+-4%7D%2C%7B+2+%2C-2+%2C+1%7D%7D

Comment: the first eigenvalue is $-3$, then you should try $A+31\!\!1$

Comment: The book gives me the characteristic polynomial $-(t+3)(t+1)^{2}$, so I thought it was i had to multiply $-3$ by$-1$

Comment: the book is right